# Hide all on sale products on Woocommerce shop page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, product

Would it be possible to hide all the products marked as "sale" on the standard WooCommerce shop page?

The sale products will be posted on a separate Sale page.

Comment: Do you have any code etc? So that we have some more context?
You could probably do this by adding a `display: none;` on the sales class.

Answer (score 0):

To hide all on sale products ***(except variable products)*** on Woocommerce shop page, use:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'on_sale_products_not_in_archives', 10, 2 );
function on_sale_products_not_in_archives( $meta_query, $query ) {
    // For woocommerce shop pages
    if( is_shop() ){
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'     => '_sale_price',
            'value'   => '',
            'compare' => '=',
        );
    }
    return $meta_query;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Tested and works.

---

If you need that on all archives pages as product category archive pages and product archive tag pages, use:

```
if( is_shop() || is_product_tag() || is_product_category() ){
```

Instead of `if( is_shop() ){`…

> For variable products it's not possible as we need to check all the product variations of a variable product.