# Hide on sale products from a shortcode on homepage in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, shortcode

I am trying to hide all the sale products on the homepage that is displaying products using Woocommerce shortcode. I am new on here and after searching high and low, I couldn't find a solution.

I have tried to use [Hide all on sale products on Woocommerce shop page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49385446/hide-all-on-sale-products-on-woocommerce-shop-page/49387489#49387489) answer code and it works on shop page.

Is there a way for this code to be applied to the homepage instead of the shop page?

I tried this slightly modified version:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'on_sale_products_not_in_archives', 10, 2 );
function on_sale_products_not_in_archives( $meta_query, $query ) {
    // For woocommerce shop pages
    if( is_page( 87 ) ){
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'     => '_sale_price',
            'value'   => '',
            'compare' => '=',
       );
    }
    return $meta_query;
}
```

But it didn't work.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter the product query with shortcodes, you need to use `woocommerce_shortcode_products_query` filter hook, but this will work on all products except variable products.

The code *(targeting home page only)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 'hide_on_sale_products_in_home', 50, 3 );
function hide_on_sale_products_in_home( $query_args, $atts, $loop_name ){
    if( is_front_page() ){

        $query_args['meta_query'] = array( array(
            'key'     => '_sale_price',
            'value'   => '',
            'compare' => '=',
        ) );
    }
    return $query_args;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

Comment: Amazing! It worked. Is there any way to make it work for variable products as well?

Comment: Read my update on this: [Hide all on sale products on Woocommerce shop page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49385446/hide-all-on-sale-products-on-woocommerce-shop-page/49387489#49387489)… So not possible on WP_Query or a WC_Query like we do here.