# Hide WooCommerce products with a Pending status from homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I have a WooCommerce [website](https://neshop.com.np) and I use WCFM multivendor plugin. When any vendor submits a product, it goes in Pending Review status, but the product is showing in the home page and when clicked on the product it shows 404 as the product status is pending and users have no permission to do this. I have tried a lot of different things, but I can't find the solution.

I have tried:

```php
function exclude_pending_products($query) { 
    // Check if it's the main query and if it's on the front-end 
    if (is_admin() || !$query->is_main_query()) { 
        return;
    }

    //Check if it's a product query 
    if ($query->is_post_type_archive('product') || $query->is_tax('product_cat') || $query->is_tax('product_tag')) { 
        //Exclude pending products
        $query->set('post_status', array('publish'));
    } 
} 
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_pending_products');
```

I tried many more things, but none worked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your theme homepage is using `[products]` shortcode to display products, like for example in WooCommerce StoreFront theme… In this case you should try the following:

```php
// For products shortcode (Home page?)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 'shortcode_product_query_excl_pending_status', 50, 3 );
function shortcode_product_query_excl_pending_status( $query_args, $atts, $loop_name ){
    $query_args['post_status'] = 'publish';
    return $query_args;
}

// For WooCommerce Archive pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'product_query_excl_pending_status', 50, 2 );
function product_query_excl_pending_status( $q, $query ) { 
    if ( ! is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() && $q->is_archive() ) { 
        $q->set('post_status', 'publish');
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It could work.

Related: [Hide on sale products from a shortcode on homepage in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53753008/hide-on-sale-products-from-a-shortcode-on-homepage-in-woocommerce/53753541#53753541)